# Finding a Galois extension( Inverse Galois problem)

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

The problem is: Find a Galois extension of the rationals so that:
$$\text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_4},$$

I know the theory behind it, but i don't have a clue where to start. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know cyclotomic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$? Try to find an $n$ such that the galois group of $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is isomorphic to that direct product.

Comment: Seconding @simo210's suggestion. Observe that finding $n$ such that $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$ has $\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ as a quotient suffices. For then a subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ will have the prescribed Galois group. Mind you, you will most likely find an exact match more quickly :-)

Comment: I know that the galois group over a cyclotomic extension of the rationals is isomorphic to the group of units of Zn. So  the Euler function of n must be equal to 8, right?

Comment: @peter271 That's right.

Comment: Thanks. But what if i have Z6xZ6 for example? If n=37 then the unit group is isomorphic to Z36 or i am getting something wrong? How can i easily find n in this case?

Comment: @peter271 yes, $(\mathbb{Z}/37\mathbb{Z})^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ since 37 is prime. This means that we need to find another $n$. Honestly I dont'know if there's a general technique other then going by cases in decomposing 36.

Comment: @peter271 $n=63$ works for this case, i'll write a full answer to recap.

Answer (score 4):

In general, when you're asked to find a Galois extensions F over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the Galois group $\text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to some direct product of abelian groups, it's always convenient to look for a cyclotomic extension for two reasons :

- Cyclotomic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ are always Galois extensions.
- The Galois group $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q(\zeta_n)}/\mathbb{Q})$ is always abelian, meaning that you can apply the decomposition theorem of finite abelian groups in order to find the direct product you are looking for.

In this case, you may find that $\mathbb{Q}\subset{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{16})}$ is our cyclotomic extension. In fact, $[\space\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{16}) : \mathbb{Q}\space]=\varphi(16)=2^4-2^3=8$, and $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q(\zeta_{16})}/\mathbb{Q})\cong(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^*$.

$(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^*$ is an abelian group of order 8, then it's isomorphic to $C_8$, $C_4\times{C_2}$ or $C_2\times{C_2}\times{C_2}$ by finite abelian groups decomposition. You can check that it's isomorphic to $C_4\times{C_2}$, because there are elements of period $4$, but there's no element of period 8 in $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^*$.

For the latter case, we want to find an $n$ such that Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})\cong(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})$.

Here, I observed that $\varphi(9)=\varphi(7)=6$ and 9 is coprime to 7, thus $\varphi(63)=\varphi(9\cdot{7})=6\cdot{6}=36$

Moreover, $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{63})/\mathbb{Q})\cong\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9)/\mathbb{Q})\times\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\mathbb{Q})$ because 9 and 7 are coprime.
Then you can find $(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^*\cong{\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^*\cong{\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}}$ for the same reasons above.